# Extracting multiple results based on multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a set of data with multiple columns: each property is located in a particular region, and has a certain return rate
Column C has names
Column F has regions
Column S has return rates

Elsewhere in the sheet, I have computed the minimum & maximum return rates for each region (3 in total).
I now want to extract the names associated with those rates.
For example, the maximum return rate for Central region is 7%.
There are 3 names which are located in Central region, and have a return rate of 7%.

How can I get all 3 of these names (no preference for display, but ideally vertically).

What I have tried so far:
=INDEX($C:$C,MATCH($B10&F10,$F:$F&$S:$S,0))
Cell B10 contains the region name
Cell F10 contains the return rate

See image; Input on the left, output on the right

[Sample Input/Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idfgh.png)

Comment: This would be a lot easier to answer with some sample data and the expected outcome. Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1456229/edit) to help us to help you

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Added - Please let me know if you have any input
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you already have the min and max values, then `INDEX/MATCH` will probably do what you want. Since you probably want to return multiple values for a given min or max, [this may be of use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642462/returning-multiple-values-with-index-and-match-without-vba)

Answer (score 0):

**You need few Array Formula to solves the issue:**

[image]

**How it works:**

1. Fill Region's name **Central** in Cell `F75` & `G75.`
2. For neatness, apply **Font Color White** on Cell `G75`.

**Note,** repeat step `1` & `2` for other Regions in `H75:K75.`

3. Fill **Max** & **Min** accordingly in `F76:K76`.
4. Enter this Array Formula in Cell `F77`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill Right.

   `{=IF(F76="Max",MAX(($B$76:$B$90=F75)*$C$76:$C$90),MIN(IF($B$76:$B$90=F75,$C$76:$C$90)))}`
5. Finally enter this Array Formula in cell `F78`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill Right then Down.

   ```
   {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$76:$C$90, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(F$75, $B$76:$B$90)*COUNTIF(F$77, $C$76:$C$90), ROW($A$76:$C$90)-MIN(ROW($A$76:$C$90))+1), ROW($A1)), COLUMN($A1)),"")}
   ```

**N.B.**

- For verification only I've Sorted source data in Range `A75:C90` on
  **Region**, you may works with original order also.
- *Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*